# If $X$ a metric space and A a subspace, then $d(x,A)$ is continuous. Show there exists $f:X\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f^{-1}(0) = A$ if $A$ closed.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm working on the assignment:

> If $(X, d)$ is a metric apace and $A$ is a subspace of $X$, then the function $d_A(x)=d(x, A)$ is continuous. Deduce that for any closed subset $A$ of $X$, there exists a continuous function $f:X\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $A=f^{-1}(0)$.

Where we defined $$d(x,A) = \inf_{a\in A} d(x,a).$$

Now this is supposed to be a hand-in which tend to be rather difficult, but the proof I came up with seems rather elementary so I'm sceptical about its correctness:

> Consider the function $f_A(x):=\min(d(x,A),1)$. Then since $d(x,A)$ is continuous by hypothesis, $f_A(x)$ is (rather trivially) also continuous. (For we simply cap the continuous $d(x,A)$ at a certain point, while ensuring that there will never be a ``jump'' from it to $1$.)
>
> Given that we're working in a metric space, we know that $d(x,A)=0$
>   if and only if $x\in A$; for if $x\in A^c$, then there exists some
>   $\epsilon >0$ such that the neighbourhood $N_\epsilon(x)\subset A^c$.
>   Because in metric spaces the complement of a closed set is open. The
>   converse ($x\in A \implies d(x,A)=0$) is true because $d(x,x)=0$, so
>   $\inf_{a\in A} d(x,A)=0$*. It thus
>   follows that $f^{-1}(0)$ is exactly equal to $A$, or:   $$A=f^{-1}(0)$$
>   * Distance is positive

I'd appreciate it if someone could take a look at this :)

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Why is $f_A(x)$ continuous? I don't understand what you mean with 'simply cap the continuous $d(x,A)$'..

Answer (score 2):

It seems right to me.
Just a little remark: your proof here works since $A$ is closed, but in general is not true that
$$ d(x,A) = 0 \iff x \in A$$
For a general subset $A$ we indeed have that
$$ d(x,A) = 0 \iff x \in \overline{A} $$
but in your case the first holds since $A$ is closed

Comment: Doesn't the sentence "for if $x\in A^c$, then there exists some $\epsilon >0$ such that the neighbourhood $N_\epsilon(x)\subset A^c$" adres this already? Because with $A$ not closed, $A^c$ not open and the argument for $d(x,A) >\epsilon>0$ no longer has to hold.

If not, how would you suggest working that in?

Comment: "Given that we're working in a metric space, we know that $d(x,A)=0$ if and only if $x \in A$"... i was just pointing out this sentence. Your argument is right

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks :)